# Using Java Files as JAR

Tags: java

If I want to use for-example some code like this in my javaApplication:   [gitHUB link for Socket](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio/tree/master/src/main/java/com/corundumstudio/socketio)

How can I include it in my project???
As all of the following lines give me error:

```
import com.corundumstudio.socketio.AckRequest;
import com.corundumstudio.socketio.Configuration;
import com.corundumstudio.socketio.SocketIOClient;
import com.corundumstudio.socketio.SocketIOServer;
import com.corundumstudio.socketio.Transport;
import com.corundumstudio.socketio.listener.*;
```

Do I have to generate a JAR or what??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project is a maven project, you will have to add dependency of the third party jar in the pom file. If its a plain eclipse project, you can add the jar to the project build dependency by going to the project properties.